# Vuejs Authentication JWT VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

Hi i do vue authentication with jwt and vuex, and works well but i need to load token and user when i refresh page. i find online this code `store.dispatch('auth/attemptAuthtoken', localStorage.getItem('authToken'))`and works good but works only in main.js . I need to put it in index.js (main file of store) but if i use it i have problem with store/dispatch etc.

I try to import store but i've problem too.

[image]
[image]

Someone can help me to fix it? (I started very recently to use vue / vuex)

**main.js**

```html
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store'

store.dispatch('auth/attemptAuthtoken', localStorage.getItem('authToken'))
store.dispatch('auth/attemptUser', JSON.parse (localStorage.getItem('user')))

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://**********/'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

**index.js**

```html
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import auth from './auth.js'




export default createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    auth
  }
})
```

Comment: The error means what it says, `store` is not defined where you use it, in app.js. It needs to be imported wherever it's used, or retrieved with `useStore`.

Comment: what do you advise me to do

Comment: See the comment above, it explains what needs to be done

Comment: You can't use store actions before installing it instance as a plugin. Just call `store.dispatch` in App.vue.